# LUA - How to stop a script from running

Tags: lua, roblox

Hello I am making a roblox LUA script and I cant figure out how to make the script stop after a if sentence.  Here my code.

```
if not newPlayer:GetRankInGroup(workspace.CoreValues.GroupID.Value) then
    teamName = "Civilian"
    (STOP)
end
```

Comment: hi, perhaps [`os.exit`](https://www.lua.org/pil/22.2.html)

Comment: Will it work on roblox ?

Comment: I doubt it, but it would be interesting to know what will happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you structure your code, you could simply `return`.

```
local shouldEscape = true
if shouldEscape then
    return
end
print("This line won't get hit")
```

But if you have set up event listeners, this won't stop those from firing. You'll need to clean those up, disable the Script, or delete the Script.

```
-- connect to a signal as an example
local connection = game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    -- if the Script is still enabled, this line will print
    print("Player Added : " .. player.Name)
end

local shouldEscape = true
if shouldEscape then
    -- disable the script
    script.Disabled = true

    -- OR : disconnect the signals
    --connection:Disconnect()

    -- OR : delete the script entirely
    --script:Destroy()

    -- escape so that no other lines execute
    return
end
print("This line won't get hit")
```